# Microsoft Edge blocked cross-domain requests

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, microsoft-edge

My application is installed on any other system and i am trying to open it on my machine with edge 38. It have a functionality where it sends request to application installed on my machine that is local host.

10.13.x.x    send to  127.0.0.1   is not working

Other browsers like IE11 / Chrome / Firefox work just fine. This circumstance is only shown in Microsoft Edge. Is there any workaround or solution about this issue?
Also it is working with machine having EDGE 20 and EDGE 40. So is it any System config issue or Browser restriction.

Answer (score -1):

Here are 2 changes that helped me fix the issue and establish a localhost WebSocket connection.

1. In the Control Panel - Internet Option, select the Security Tab. In the Security tab, select Local intranet zone. Click on Sites button and uncheck all checkboxes in Local intranet dialog. OR
2. In the Control Panel - Internet Option, select the Security Tab. In the Security tab, select Local intranet zone. Click on Sites button and then on Advanced button in the Local intranet dialog, add the required web address to the same zone as localhost.